# How to filter django rest framework serializers's drowp down items?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to assign Tasks to only the staffs. Therefore, I want my dorpdown list should only show the users that have a role of is_staff = True.

But my drop down list now shows all the users (Superuser, Authority, General_user) that are available in the database.

[image]

How to modify this to only show staffs in the drop down list which should only show two users since I've assigned two users with staff role...?

**My Model Classes:**

**Custom-User Model:**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    Responsible for handleing App user's data
    """
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    nid = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(
        upload_to=FileManager.photo_path, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_authority = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_specialist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_general_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    timestamps = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    objects = user_manager.UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['nid']
```

**Tasks Model**

```
class Task(BaseAbstractModel):
    '''
    Responsible for Storing and Providing Tasks data
    '''
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(Assignment,
                                   on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                   related_name='+')
    assigne_to = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                   on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                   related_name='+')

    task_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    is_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                   on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
                                   related_name='created_by')
```

**Serializer:**

```
class TaskListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    '''
    Will be serializing Task's data
    '''

    created_by = UserListSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('assignment',
                  'assigne_to',
                  'task_name',
                  'is_done',
                  'created_by',)
```

**Generic Create View**

```
class CreateTaskView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskListSerializer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) with [`queryset`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#the-queryset-argument) argument:

```
class TaskListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    '''
    Will be serializing Task's data
    '''

    created_by = UserListSerializer(read_only=True)
    assigne_to = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.filter(is_staff=True))

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('assignment',
                  'assigne_to',
                  'task_name',
                  'is_done',
                  'created_by',)
```